Extract block to code behind is no longer available in .NET 8 and Visual Studio 2022
I'm using .NET 8 and Blazor in Visual Studio 2022 and I want to move my C# code to a code behind file. There is supposed to be an option called "Extract block to code behind" if you highlight the code block in the .razor page, I've watched a tutorial on this but I don't have that option in my editor.
Has this been removed from .NET 8 or am I missing a setting of some sort?
It seems to be a general issue with the QuickActions menu, it doesn't appear if I press Ctrl+. or right click on the menu options

It works OK over here, VS 17.9.3.
Do not "highlight the code block" but just place your cursor in the @code word and then press Ctrl+.

Visual Studio Information
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.9.6


The reason this was not working for me was because there were
Razor Comments in the @code { } section of the razor page

Solution

Only use C# Comments in the @code { } section of the .razor file

Using Razor Comments in the @code { } section of the razor file makes is so
Visual Studio won't provide the Extract block to code behind Quick Action
Incorrect Example
Example.razor
<div>Not Working</div>

@code {
    private void Method()
    {    
        @* This type of comment DOES NOT work                 *@
        @* Extract code block to code behind is NOT available *@
    }
}

Correct Example
Example.razor
<div>This Works</div>

@code {
    private void Method()
    {
        // This type of comment WORKS
        /* This type of comment WORKS */
        // Extract code block to code behind IS available
    }
}

